# Proving that this statement is a theorem of our proof system

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

So I need to produce a proof tree of the below statement using the introduction and elimination rules.

$$
\begin{array}{c}
x \in a &q  \\ 
\hline
 \exists x \colon a \bullet q \\
\hline
((\exists x \colon a \bullet p) \land (\forall x \colon a \bullet p \implies q)) \implies (\exists x \colon a \bullet q)
\end{array}
$$

I know I'll have to do an exists introduction as the next step but am I on the right track?  The example I have does two trees, one for the right side and one for the left.  I'm confused about where I need to go with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $p$ and $q$ may contain instances of $x$?  If so, I really prefer to work with $\exists x \ p(x)$ rather than $\forall x \ p$.  Also, I'll leave out the $x \in a$ part ... you can add it back in if you want, but here is the basic proof:

\begin{align}
\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{\exists x \ p(x) \land \forall x (p(x) \to q(x))^1}{\cfrac{\exists x \ p(x)}{p(a)}{\ \exists E} \qquad \cfrac{\forall x (p(x) \to q(x))}{p(a) \to q(a)}{\ \forall E}}{\ \land E}}{q(a)}{\ \to E}}{\exists x \ q(x)}{\ \exists I}}{(\exists x \ P(x)) \land \forall x (p(x) \to q(x))) \to \exists x \ q(x)}{\ \to I^1}
\end{align}

The subscript $1$ shows which statement is being discharged at which point in the proof.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  So, from looking at your suggestion I've come up with this: 
\begin{align}
\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{(\exists x \colon a \bullet p ) \land (\forall x \colon a \bullet p \to q)^1}{\cfrac{\exists x \ \colon a \bullet p}{p}{\ [\exists \ Elim]} \qquad \cfrac{\forall x  \colon a \bullet p \to q}{p \to q}{\ [\forall \ Elim]}}{\ [\land Elim]}}{q}{\ [\to Elim]}}{\exists x \colon a \bullet q}{\ [\exists \ Intro]}}{(\exists x \colon a \bullet p ) \land (\forall x \colon a \bullet p  \to q)) \to (\exists x \colon a \bullet q)}{\ [\to Intro]^1}
\end{align}

Comment: Hi, statements are of the form: quantifier quantification 'bullet' predicate.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA   I interpreted the $\exists x : a$ as specifying the type for the variable, e.g. you could have something like $\exists x : \mathbb{N} ...$, and the bullt as 'such that'. So the $a$ is not itself a claim (which is why I left it out completely), though we could of course add the claim $x \in a$. And by the way, I took the formatting from one of your Answers, so thanks for that!! :)